# server link - mysql and sql 2008 server link

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have done data migration using server link in sql 2008.But  at the moment it is not working.

**Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSQL".OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSQL" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider +Data source name not found and no default driver specified". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7303)**

Please help me to solve this issues.

Comment: Is the data source available?

Comment: yes.All the data sources are available..

Comment: @TRS: have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Please check our DSN connection.

You might be add it into User DSN instead of System DSN.

If you add DSN into User DSN, it will return 7303 error code, but if you create DSN as system DSN it will work.